# Controlling Visibility Of Imported Categories

Tags: c#, revit-api

I am writing a program to turn off certain "sub-categories" from imported AutoCAD files (such as "DEFPOINTS", which arguably should automatically be hidden or not plot in Revit).  The following code seems like it should work, but instead kicks back an odd error.

```
Transaction Do_Filtered_VG = new Transaction(doc, "FilteredVG")
Autodesk.Revit.DB.View CurrentView = doc.ActiveView;
Categories categories = doc.Settings.Categories; string CatUp = string.Empty;
List<Category> ToBeOff = new List<Category>();
List<string> myCategories = new List<string>();
foreach (Category c in categories)
{
    if (c.Name.ToLower().EndsWith("dwg"))
    {
        List<Category> SubCategories = new List<Category>();
        foreach (Category One_Cat in c.SubCategories)
        {
            CatUp = One_Cat.Name.ToUpper();
            if (CatUp.Contains("DEFPOINTS") || CatUp.Contains("NPLT") || CatUp.Contains("RDFF") || CatUp.Contains("SDFF") || CatUp.Contains("DUCT"))//or other pattern;
            {
                 myCategories.Add(One_Cat.Name); ToBeOff.Add(One_Cat);
            }
        }
    }
}
Do_Filtered_VG.Start();
foreach (Category One_Cat in ToBeOff)
{
    CurrentView.SetVisibility(One_Cat, false);
}
Do_Filtered_VG.Commit();
TestCodeX.If_Tony("Would Turn Off Layers:", TestCodeX.List_To_Dialog(myCategories));
```

The error given is: Cannot set the visible attribute of the category Level 3 because it is user hiddenA transaction or sub-transaction was opened but not closed".  This is odd, because "Level 3" is not a category, but is the ActiveView.

But my transaction is opened and closed.  I was not able to find hiddenA in an online search.  I also tried using the construction:  One_Cat.get_Visibility(CurrentView) (to try to at least see if the category is visible), and this resulted in the same error.  I also changed my references from RevitAPI (2014) to (2015) and (2016), with no change in the error.  My code properly filtered the layer names I wanted to turn off, as evidenced in my "Would Turn Off Layers:" TaskDialog echo of myCategories.  But whenever the .SetVisibility line was not commented out, I get the error described.

Is there some other method of turning off(on) visibility of Categories in the RevitAPI?  Or is there some other Transaction method required other than the one I am using?

Answer (score 0):

There are some internal categories that exist, but you can't set the visibility on. I don't have the SDK handy, but there's a property along the lines of "Category.AllowsVisibilityControl[view]" that will tell you whether it is legitimate to hide that category in the current view.

So you would do something like this in your code:

```
// inside your existing IF about the category name...
if (One_Cat.AllowsVisibilityControl[CurrentView])
{     
    myCategories.Add(One_Cat.Name); ToBeOff.Add(One_Cat);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try.  However, since these "categories" are actually just ACAD layer names (and none are internal/protected categories), I cannot see that it would make a difference.  If the program kicks back that I cannot change the visibility of the "category", I'm back where I started.  No changes would occur, but I wouldn't get an error.

Comment: Oddly, this is the first "answer" in StackOverFlow I have received that actually provided a nugget of the answer.  The .AllowsVisibilityControl[CurrentView] was actually (in RevitAPI R14) .get_AllowsVisibilityControl(CurrentView), but the crux was correct.   Also, I ran a new transaction inside my foreach (Category One_Cat in ToBeOff)... and this helped.

Comment: Glad to hear it - yeah I was writing in C# syntax, which is a bit different, particular on the "get_" prefix for some indexed properties.   Soooo if it helped, how about an "up-vote" on the answer?

Comment: Because of multiple questions that nobody was able to answer (which the "powers that be" therefore deemed to be bad questions) I don't have permission to vote on questions or answers.  I am also blocked from asking more questions.  Seems a bit dictatorial.

Answer (score 0):

I see one problem with transactions in your code: you create a new transaction, but never call either `Start` or `Commit` on it.

Please read The Building Coder topic group on [Handling Transactions and Transaction Groups](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.53) about using transactions and enclosing them in a `using` statement.

Comment: The problem is, I BOTH .Start and .Commit the transaction, at the bottom of my code.  Is there some magic in having the definition of the Transaction immediately before the .Start?  Also, I can see the "using" helping to  "catch" a transaction that didn't start, but the transaction in question both starts and commits without kicking the error, as long as I do something other than "SetVisibility", so I don't see the exact structure (you love so much) being the issue.  I have a dozen programs with dozens of Transactions done the same way I've seen in many other people's code.

Comment: The MAIN problem is, the above counts as an "answer" to my question when in fact it addresses not a single aspect of the question.  In what way does it tell me how to control visibility of ACAD layers in a view?  Obviously, it would be best if "answers" that do not answer the question be deleted.